# Waiting for n channels with core.async

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

In the same way `alt!` waits for **one of** n channels to get a value, I'm looking for the idiomatic way to wait for **all** n channels to get a value.

I need this because I "spawn" n go blocks to work on async tasks, and I want to know when they are all done. I'm sure there is a very beautiful way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say `(mapv #(async/<!! %) channels)`.

If you wanted to handle individual values as they arrive, and then do something special after the final channel produces a value, you can use exploit the fact that `alts!` / `alts!!` take a vector of channels, and they are functions, not macros, so you can easily pass in dynamically constructed vectors.

So, you can use `alts!!` to wait on your initial collection of n channels, then use it again on the remaining channels etc.

```
(def c1 (async/chan))
(def c2 (async/chan))

(def out
  (async/thread
    (loop [cs [c1 c2] vs []]
      (let [[v p] (async/alts!! cs)
            cs (filterv #(not= p %) cs)
            vs (conj vs v)]
        (if (seq cs)
          (recur cs vs)
          vs)))))

(async/>!! c1 :foo)
(async/>!! c2 :bar)

(async/<!! out)
;= [:foo :bar]
```

If instead you wanted to take all values from all the input channels and then do something else when they all close, you'd want to use `async/merge`:

> clojure.core.async/merge
>   ([chs] [chs buf-or-n])
>     Takes a collection of source channels and returns a channel which
>     contains all values taken from them. The returned channel will be
>     unbuffered by default, or a buf-or-n can be supplied. The channel
>     will close after all the source channels have closed.

Comment: Thanks! I think `merge` is what I need.

Comment: Great! NB. I've just added in the simplest solution for waiting for a single value from each channel (as opposed to all values before all channels close), which is `(mapv #(async/<!! %) channels)` – somehow it went MIA in the initial version.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `core.async` `map` function:

```
(<!! (a/map vector [ch1 ch2 ch3]))
;; [val-from-ch-1 val-from-ch2 val-from-ch3]
```

Comment: If wondering, `vector` is for returning a vector of the first value taken from every channel. I guess `seq` would do as well, right?

Comment: The lambda to a/map is invoked with as many args as channels, so seq wouldn't work.  Maybe you are looking for a/merge?